# Struts 2 Jquery Plugin require internet connection

Tags: jquery-plugins, struts2

I am using struts2-jquery pluglin. it requires internet connection. It works perfectly whenever i have internet connection. Following errors occures whenever i am trying to run my project without internet connection

```
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin;F:\java\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;F:\java\apache-cxf-2.4.2\bin;F:\eclipse-jee-indigo-win32\eclipse;;.
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 653 ms
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.19
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor airtel.xml from F:\java\eclipsework\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:airtel' did not find a matching property.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.tiles.context.AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - Class: java.net.PlainSocketImpl
File: PlainSocketImpl.java
Method: connect
Line: 195 - java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java:195:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: Unable to load jar:file:/F:/java/eclipsework/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/airtel/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.2.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml - Class: java.net.PlainSocketImpl
File: PlainSocketImpl.java
Method: connect
Line: 195 - java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java:195:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:890)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:144)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: struts.apache.org - Class: java.net.PlainSocketImpl
File: PlainSocketImpl.java
Method: connect
Line: 195 - java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java:195:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:885)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:677)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1315)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1282)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1194)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1090)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1003)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
    ... 20 more

Jan 2, 2012 3:01:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/airtel] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 2, 2012 3:01:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1221 ms
```

Comment: yes..it requires internet connection to work.

Comment: have you put this entry `loadFromGoogle = true` in your head tag??

Comment: How can i run it without internet connection

Comment: @Vishnu: have you set this `loadFromGoogle = true` entry in the head tag?? if yes that means plugin will try to load the jquery files from Google CDN else they will be loaded from the jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Commenters: I don't understand why you don't put this in as an answer.

Usually the jQuery plugin doesn't need internet connection, it should work locally without problems unless you have set the attribute `loadFromGoogle="true"` in the `<sj:head>` tag of the JSP in which your HTML code resides. If you did so, the `<sj:head>` gets translated to HTML code with a `<link>` to a file on a Google server, which will only work if you have an internet connection.

If this isn't the problem, I can only imagine two more.

1) I've never seen this line, and I also develop in a Tomcat 7 in Eclipse (even though I didn't use update 19 of Tomcat so far): `WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:airtel' did not find a matching property.` But I don't think this is the problem.

2) You have business logic in a servlet that tries to connect to an internet resource, this might just not work; as the exception gets thrown in a foolproof JRE class it shouldn't fail.